# Replacing values of a row with values from another row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace the values in the first row of my dataframe with the values in the second row, so that they are both the same, but without changing the index. To further explain:

```
column 1  column 2  column 3

day 1      x         x         x

day 2      y         y         y

day 3      z         z         z
```

So I want to replace the x values with the y values and didn't manage to make it work. I have tried with both iloc and loc functions with no success.

Comment: Please share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[1]
df

      column 1 column 2 column 3
day 1        y        y        y
day 2        y        y        y
day 3        z        z        z
```